# Interface Orientation Issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, webview, orientation

I'm with a little problem. I have a TabBarController in my app, then one of the elements inside the tab bar is a navigation controller. 
Well, inside my navigation controller, i want to play a video using web view.
My problem is: It's necessary to change the interface orientation of my web view. When i put a little bit of code, returning YES on the method shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (only for my web view's class), the video is still not changing the interface. 
I've used a modal view controller to run my video, but we can see the same problem.
I don't have any idea about how to fix it, because i used all of my ios's knowledge.
Is there something to put inside my modal view controller to change my interface orientation?
My app has this kind of structure:

```
TabBarController->NavigationController ->VIew A->View B(Inside the View B, a ModalViewController)
```

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question, you want to force the orientation of the device. This can be done by modifying the orientation of the status bar:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft animated:NO];
```

For this to work, your app should be set so to support autorotation (returning YES from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` for all orientations); since you are using a navigation controller, also its root controller should return YES from `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`.

You can call the above method when you need to switch orientation, i.e., at the moment you are going to play the video (when you load the web view, possibly).

Comment: Well, i want to force it, but for all orientations, not just for one specific

Comment: I will put this inside my viewDidLoad? or the shouldAutorotate method?

Comment: you can put this exactly in the place where you are going to play the video.

Comment: which method? i putted this on the viewDidLoad and the xCode called an exception...

Comment: [BlocoNavViewController setSelectedIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71923d0

'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[BlocoNavViewController setSelectedIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x71923d0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1c9f012 0x10dce7e 0x1d2a4bd 0x1c8ebbc 0x1c8e94e 0x4fb6 0x10f0705 0x27920 0x278b8 0xe8671 0xe8bcf 0xe7d38 0x5733f 0x57552 0x353aa 0x26cf8 0x1bfadf9 0x1bfaad0 0x1c14bf5 0x1c14962 0x1c45bb6 0x1c44f44 0x1c44e1b 0x1bf97e3 0x1bf9668 0x2465c 0x1f5d 0x1e85)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)

Comment: that error has nothing to do with the call to `setStatusBarOrientation`... you are sending the `setSelectedIndex` on the BlocoNavViewController that has no such method...

Comment: ok ok, sorry about that. But still not working here.
I realized that my orientation is only supported if i go to the Project Properties and select them.